# How to export mongo data into csv using pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, export-to-csv

My code :

```
data = db.get_collection('activity_tracker').find({"companyId" : "527d4b23-347a-4ad2-81d8-dfd66af5631a", 'userEmail':{'$ne':'abc@xyz.in'}})

with open('asdxk.csv', 'w') as outfile:

    fields = ['companyId', 'userEmail']
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, fields)
    for post in data:
        writer.writerow([post])
```

Problem statement :

Using above code I am exporting data to CSV file as a junk but what i want to do is companyID  and  userEmail details should be export to csv as row and column format. Header name should be companyID and  userEmail.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)** utility  to export the data to csv:

```
mongoexport -h localhost -d test -c activity_tracker --type=csv
--fields companyId,userEmail 
--q '{"companyId":"527d4b23-347a-4ad2-81d8-dfd66af5631a","userEmail":{"$ne":"abc@xyz.in"}}' 
--out asdxk.csv
```